# How to query distinct values from map with given key in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, dictionary, hql

I have following Hibernate 3 mapping for User class:

```
<class name="org.test.User" table="users">

... some other mapping...

    <map name="metadata" table="user_metadata">
        <cache usage="transactional"/>
        <key column="user_id" not-null="true" foreign-key="FK_USERMETADATA_USER_ID"/>
        <map-key type="string" column="datum_key" length="255" />
        <element type="string" column="datum_value" length="1024" not-null="true"/>
    </map>            
</class>
```

I would like to retrieve a list of all datum_values with given datum_key.

In SQL the query would look like:

```
select distinct datum_value from user_metadata where datum_key = 'Member Type'
```

What would be the most feasible approach? Create a new Hibernate mapping for the user_metadata as well? Or try to come up a HQL/JPA QL query using indices/elements returning (possibly scalar) values? So far I tried HQL/JPA QL approach a bit and I did not get too far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to your above SQL query in HQL. [indices()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) function as well as index dereferencing can only be used in 'WHERE' clause.

The easiest solution is to map your SQL query as named query and run it as [scalar native SQL query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13646).